# Variable returns null when called from a Stateless to Stateful Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map, that has these `labels`.

```
final Map<int, int> labels = {
  1: 8,
  2: 24,
  3: 6,
  4: 12,
  5: 32,
  6: 2,
  7: 8,
  8: 77,
};
```

It can be called using the variable 'selected'

```
class Score extends StatelessWidget 
{
   final int selected;
   Score(this.selected);
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text('You're score is ${labels[selected]}',
         style: TextStyle(
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: "Netflix"));
   }
}
```

This is connected to a `StreamBuilder` in another class Card1 that extends as a `Stateful` Widget as :

```
class Card1 extends StatefulWidget 
{
    @override
    Card1({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    Card1State createState() => Card1State();
}

class Card1State extends State<Card1> 
{  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ... //other code,
    StreamBuilder(
              stream: _dividerController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
              ? Score(snapshot.data)
              : Container(),
       ),
}
```

My problem is that I can not call the value of `selected` from my `Score` class to my `Card1` class and it always returns `null`.

How do I call the value of selected to `Card1` class?

Edit: This is my full-source code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter_spinning_wheel/flutter_spinning_wheel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Map<int, int> labels = {
  1: 8,
  2: 24,
  3: 6,
  4: 12,
  5: 32,
  6: 2,
  7: 8,
  8: 77,
};

class Card1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Card1({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  Card1State createState() => Card1State();
}

class Card1State extends State<Card1> {
  String spinReward;

  final StreamController _dividerController = StreamController<int>();
  final _wheelNotifier = StreamController<double>();

  double _generateRandomVelocity() => (Random().nextDouble() * 6000) + 2000;
  double _generateRandomAngle() => Random().nextDouble() * pi * 2;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dividerController.close();
    _wheelNotifier.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [const Color(0xFFFFFFF), const Color(0xFFFFFFF)],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return true;
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SpinningWheel(
                    Image.asset('assets/app/Card1-8-300.png'),
                    width: 350,
                    height: 350,
                    initialSpinAngle: _generateRandomAngle(),
                    spinResistance: 0.6,
                    canInteractWhileSpinning: false,
                    dividers: 8,
                    onUpdate: _dividerController.add,
                    onEnd: _dividerController.add,
                    secondaryImage:
                        Image.asset('assets/app/Card1-center-300.png'),
                    secondaryImageHeight: 110,
                    secondaryImageWidth: 110,
                    shouldStartOrStop: _wheelNotifier.stream,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: _dividerController.stream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) =>
                        snapshot.hasData ? Score(snapshot.data) : Container(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "SPIN NOW!",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontFamily: "Netflix",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Color(0xFFFE524B),
                    onPressed: () {
                      spinWheel();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  spinWheel() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      //labels[selected] is null
      spinReward = "${labels[selected]}";
      print(spinReward);
    });
    _wheelNotifier.sink.add(_generateRandomVelocity());
  }
}

class Score extends StatelessWidget {
  //This is the value of selected I want to call in my other class
  final int selected;
  Score(this.selected);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `selected`??

Comment: I am calling it on an onTap function in my build context in the Card1 class.

Comment: The value of selected is not `snapshot.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable `int selected` in `Card1State`

```
class Card1State extends State<Card1> 
{  
    int selected;
}
```

Set the selected value when create `Score`

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ... //other code,
    StreamBuilder(
              stream: _dividerController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
              ? Score(selected = snapshot.data)
              : Container(),
       ),
```

Comment: cannot implement this since the var selected must necessarily be final

Comment: Why ??
```class Card1State extends State<Card1> 
{  
   int selected;
}
```

Comment: Because its a Stateful Widget

Comment: `Card1State` is not a Stateful Widget!

Comment: but it extends Card1 which is a stateful widget!

Comment: but you can add a new variable `int selected` in `Card1State`...

Comment: When I call a new variable, it doesn't inherit from another class, hence it returns null. I need to call that specific value of selected in my Stateful widget.

Comment: Please show the full codes. Or see how to manage state :https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: Hi, I've added the whole source code, please give it a look. I appreciate your time & effort. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the another class ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208768/discussion-between-simran-aswani-and-kahou).